# CAGradientLayer not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer, cagradientlayer

I created a new project. I linked `QuartzCore.framework` and imported `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in the `ViewController.m`.

And here is the code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"view height %f", self.view.frame.size.height); // returns 667 on iPhone 6
    NSLog(@"view width %f", self.view.frame.size.width); // returns 375 on iPhone 6

    NSLog(@"layers count %lu", self.view.layer.sublayers.count); // returns 2

    // Gradient
    UIColor *colorOne = [UIColor blueColor];
    UIColor *colorTwo = [UIColor greenColor];
    NSArray *colorArray = @[colorOne, colorTwo];

    NSNumber *locationOne = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
    NSNumber *locationTwo = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    NSArray *locationArray = @[locationOne, locationTwo];

    CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradientLayer.frame = self.view.frame;
    gradientLayer.colors = colorArray;
    gradientLayer.locations = locationArray;

    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0];
    //[self.view.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayer above:[self.view.layer.sublayers firstObject]]; // didn't work either

    NSLog(@"layers count %lu", self.view.layer.sublayers.count); //returns 3
}
```

I tried setting the view's background color to `clearColor`, calling it in the `viewDidAppear`, but none of them worked. I really don't know what I'm missing. Thanks in any help.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Your color array should be `NSArray *colorArray = @[(id)colorOne.CGColor, (id)colorTwo.CGColor];`, because the `colors` array takes `CGColorRef`s, rather than `UIColor`s, annoyingly enough - see [the CGGradientLayer docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAGradientLayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CAGradientLayer/startPoint)

Comment: The annoying part is not that CGColor is needed but that using UIColor instead does not cause any complaint in the console. I wish I had a nickel for every time I've made this mistake...

Comment: I totally missed that! Glad I asked. Thank you :)

Comment: @matt Exactly! Good to know it's not just me :)

Comment: Wow! never thought they wont notice us. Good catch

Comment: An ooolllld problem...

Comment: @matt Thanks for this hint. Otherwise I might have spent some more time wondering why it is not working...

Comment: I just spent a full hour trying to figure out what I was doing wrong, only to find out I had forgotten .cgColor on my UIColor calls. Jesus.

Comment: @nickdnk try 3 hours, lol. Godsent answer.